# how to use ng-show with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have tried all the solutions i could find but i am stuck. I have 2 checkboxes, HBO and Marvin. Marvin needs to show a div. HBO needs to show nothing. It works until I need to click the checkbox twice for it to show/hide. usually this would be a $apply() issue but that does not seem to be the case. I believe I am not updating the model correctly. I forgot to mention that the checkboxes need to reset to false when the other is true.
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uPQYKA3BGy7VJWZeAaKr?p=preview)

```
 var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.showMeMarvin = function () {
        if (ctrl.show === true) {
            //$timeout(function () {
            ctrl.marvin = false;
            ctrl.show = false;
            ctrl.hbo = false;
            //})
        }
        else {
            //$timeout(function () {
            ctrl.marvin = true;
            ctrl.show = true;
            ctrl.hbo = false;
            //})
        }
    };

    ctrl.showMeHBO = function () {
        if (ctrl.show === true) {
            // $timeout(function () {
            ctrl.show = false;
            ctrl.hbo = true;
            ctrl.marvin = false;
            //})
        }
        else {
            //$timeout(function () {
            ctrl.marvin = false;
            ctrl.hbo = true;
            //})
        }
    };
```

Comment: should use `ng-checked` while using `ng-model` http://plnkr.co/edit/YwWsos2UyvJLh5s1s0pB?p=preview YOu could find github link here https://github.com/netman92/angular.js/commit/78bc5a91ac74a4c57706a775fb9589358b8009cc

Comment: I forgot to mention that the checkboxes need to reset to false when the other is true.

Comment: Are you trying to make the content visible only when Marvin is checked but HBO is not? e.g. http://plnkr.co/edit/Y0DNwmFr9fdwFhLLYPUS?p=preview

Comment: yes that is correct. please see update

Comment: ah didn't see your comment about resetting one checkbox to false when the other is set to true. You should be using radio inputs instead of checkboxes if that is the case

Comment: @texas697 Why do you use checkboxes if you actually want the behavior of radio button group?

Comment: I can do that, I was trying to get it to work with a checkbox switch for looks. either way will work. what ever you can put in plunker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the div ng-show like this:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12" ng-show="checkedHBO == 1">
```

And it will work without any additional functions calls.

Edit:
To have it working with the condition to reset the prev selected value you can use this:

```
<div ng-controller="ShowController as ctrl">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <label for="checkedHBO" class="ts-label">HBO</label>
    <input id="checkedHBO" name="mygroup" type="radio" value="hbo"  ng-model="checkedHBO" ng-change="checkedMarvin = undefined"/>
    <label for="checkedMarvin" class="ts-label">Marvin</label>
    <input id="checkedMarvin" name="mygroup" type="radio" value="marvin" ng-model="checkedMarvin" ng-change="checkedHBO = undefined"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12" ng-show="checkedHBO">
    <center>
      <div class="jumbotron">
                 DIV 1
                </div>
      <div class="jumbotron">
                  DIV 2
                </div>
      <div class="jumbotron">
                  DIV 3
                </div>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show me in a plunker. it is not working for me

Comment: Check this example to fit your second requirement:http://plnkr.co/edit/fYWRS52CIGcJznLlfnbL?p=preview

Comment: put in answer please. actually i need to leave the ng-models named differently

Comment: how can i do this with the ng-models staying as they are. actually i dont think that is necessary

Comment: updated the answer to have the model defined as in the initial plnkr

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a radio input instead of checkboxes. http://plnkr.co/edit/hE68w9RKUoFamAWGgRzR?p=preview

```
<input name="radio" id="checkedHBO" type="radio"  ng-model="ctrl.show" ng-value="false" />
<input name="radio" id="checkedMarvin" type="radio" ng-model="ctrl.show" ng-value="true"/>
```